# QtMetaObject unresolved external Error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to implement a simple server client application in QT. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
Here's the Header File to my client class.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef  Client_H
#define Client_H

#include <QTcpSocket>


class Client : public QObject 
{   Q_OBJECT

public: 
     explicit Client (QObject *parent = 0);

     void Connect(); 

signals: 

public slots: 

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket; 
};
#endif
```

and here's the code to Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"

Client::Client(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Client::Connect()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this); 
    socket->connectToHost("192.168.10.10", 8016); 
    if (socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        printf("COnnected");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not Connected");
    }
}
```

as you can see it's pretty simple. In my Main.cpp i create an instance of the client class and then call the function Connect():

```
Client Test;
Test.Connect();
```

When building my project i get the following errors

```
1>Client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl Client::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Client@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>Client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl Client::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@Client@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
1>Client.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl Client::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@Client@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

I know that this Error means that the functions are declared but the definition is missing. I just don't know where to find these definitions and which file i have to link to get rid of these errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are automatically generated by the `moc` tool. Did you set it up to run whenever your header file changed? Did you run it manually? If not, consider installing the [Qt Visual Studio tools](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/index.html) that solve this for you.

Comment: Hey thanks ! I already installed the Qt Visual Studio Tools ! how can i set the moc tool up to run automatically though?

Comment: How did you create your project and `Client.h` file? Presumably the add-in needs to add a build step to call `moc` for you, which does not happen if you add a regular header/cpp file pair.

Comment: my Project is a standard visual Studio Project. I added client.h as a regular header file. How to add it correctly ?

Comment: Create your progject from the "Qt Application" template as per [the getting started](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-getting-started.html) documentation. Alternatively, write a CMake configuration and import that in Visual Studio. As a bonus your project can then be compiled to all other platforms.

Comment: Thanks ! would it also work if I simply configured the custom build Rules in Visual Studios and chose moc.exe to build the Client header file ??

Comment: For some interpretation of "simply" ;) I try to avoid these build configuration-specific properties because they are never in sync and hard to fix.